# Can I SSH into my Amazon EC2 server instance if I don't have .pem file from when instance was created?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I am working with some Amazon EC2 servers that are up and running, and I need to SSH into the servers. I don't have any keys that were generated when the servers were first set up (someone else did it long before I got here). Can I still get into the servers without the key files?

FWIW I've tried a lot of things to SSH into the box so far, including generating new key pairs in the EC2 dashboard, and nothing seems to be working. [This Amazon AWS support post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=416618) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14107507/284698) seem to indicate that I'm out of luck unless I want to make an AMI of my current server and then use it to instantiate a whole new EC2 server instance (just to get the .pem file generated at that time). Is that really the only way I can get into the box at this point?!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In short: Yes, you can, but not without some work.

You'll need to do the following:

(For these steps, assume that the machine you're having trouble connecting to is called server-01.)

**First, before starting these steps, take a snapshot of your server.**

1. Start a new, temporary instance. Call it server-02.
2. Stop server-01. **Don't terminate it, just stop it.**
3. Un-attach the root (`/`) EBS volume from server-01, and attach it to server-02 as, say `/dev/sdb`.
4. Sign into server-02, and run: `$ mkdir /mnt/temp && mount /dev/sdb /mnt/temp`. This will mount server-01's root partition within the (temporary) server-02.
5. Now you should be able to: `$ vi /home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` and copy/paste in your public key. When you've done that, save and close the file.
6. Now run: `$ cd / && umount /mnt/temp` to umount server-01's root partition from server-02.
7. Now, just un-attach that volume from server-02, attach it back to server-01, and then start server-01. When it starts up, you should be able to ssh in again.

Comment: Just to add to this excellent answer, I found this blog post which walks through doing it from the command line. http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip before anyone tries [EEAA](https://serverfault.com/users/20815/eeaa)'s answer,

If you have not run the `iptables save` or `iptables-save` command to save your configurations, then just restart the server. Citing this answer on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/842315), I learnt that `iptables` saves your configurations in the RAM itself unless you explicitly save it to the configuration files.

EC2 instances can be easily rebooted from the EC2 Dashboard or `aws-cli`

Comment: Umm, it looks like an answer to another question mistakenly posted here. There is nothing about firewall/iptables in this question.

Comment: My bad, this answer is for when all traffic gets blocked to a server if all IP addresses are blocked. Let me know if it needs to be taken down.