# How can I add Amazon EBS drive to instance with two EBS drives already?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Per [this excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/477488/can-i-ssh-into-my-amazon-ec2-server-instance-if-i-dont-have-pem-file-from-when/477492#477492), I'm trying to disconnect an EBS drive from one instance (Server-01) and connect it to another instance (Server-02), where I will mount it and get access to a file I need. Then I'll disconnect it from Server-02 and move it back to Server-01.

Here's the problem. Server-02, the server where I want to add the drive, won't let me associate the EBS drive that I've disconnected from Server-01. Could it be because Server-02 already has two EBS drives attached to it (an 8 GB drive at `/dev/sda1`, and a 20 GB drive at `/dev/sdf`)?

(Please pardon me if I don't have my terminology exactly correct.)

Comment: Does AWS give you an error message when you try to attach the EBS volume?  If so, *what is it?*

Comment: did you try mounting it on /dev/sdg maybe?

Comment: Are both, Server-01 and Server-02, in the same Availability Zone? Amazon AWS will not let you attach an EBS Volume in *Availability Zone - 1* with an instance that was launched in *Availability Zone - 2*.

Comment: Rhetonik- that was it; turns out my drive was created in us-west-1c and Server-02 was in us-west-1b. (I made the drive with the "quick" wizard instead of the classic wizard so I was never prompted for a zone.) Thank you! If you'd like to answer the question with that, I'd be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a snapshot of the EBS volume located in us-west-1c on Server-01, you can create a new volume from that snapshot in a different availability zone (us-west-1b in your case), and then attach this new volume to Server-02.

If you only intended to move data in one direction, this would be fairly quick and clean, and you can dispose of the Snapshot+EBS Volume once you're done without any disruption to the original EBS mount on Server-01. If you wanted to then move data back from Server-02 to Server-01, you'd need to repeat the process in reverse.