# Amazon EC2 unable to connect to instance

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, amazon-ec2, connection, startup

I had to change keypair on my instance. I have created an EBS AMI image of the original instance and created a new one with the image. I can ping the instance but ssh connection is refused.

One thing that may be causig the problem is that a passphrase is required for my ssl certificate on apache, because that is the last thing I can see in the syslog.

The syslog:

```
      Xen Minimal OS!
  start_info: 0x1890000(VA)
    nr_pages: 0x1e0000
  shared_inf: 0xbf217000(MA)
     pt_base: 0x1893000(VA)
nr_pt_frames: 0x11
    mfn_list: 0x990000(VA)
   mod_start: 0x0(VA)
     mod_len: 0
       flags: 0x0
    cmd_line: root=/dev/sda1 ro 4
  stack:      0x94f860-0x96f860
MM: Init
      _text: 0x0(VA)
     _etext: 0x5ffbd(VA)
   _erodata: 0x78000(VA)
     _edata: 0x80ae0(VA)
stack start: 0x94f860(VA)
       _end: 0x98fe68(VA)
  start_pfn: 18a7
    max_pfn: 1e0000
Mapping memory range 0x1c00000 - 0x1e0000000
setting 0x0-0x78000 readonly
skipped 0x1000
MM: Initialise page allocator for 27a0000(27a0000)-1e0000000(1e0000000)
MM: done
Demand map pfns at 1e0001000-21e0001000.
Heap resides at 21e0002000-41e0002000.
Initialising timer interface
Initialising console ... done.
gnttab_table mapped at 0x1e0001000.
Initialising scheduler
Thread "Idle": pointer: 0x21e0002010, stack: 0x36f0000
Initialising xenbus
Thread "xenstore": pointer: 0x21e00027c0, stack: 0x3700000
Dummy main: start_info=0x96f960
Thread "main": pointer: 0x21e0002f70, stack: 0x3710000
"main" "root=/dev/sda1" "ro" "4" 
vbd 2049 is hd0
******************* BLKFRONT for device/vbd/2049 **********


backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/513/2049
Failed to read /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/513/2049/feature-barrier.
Failed to read /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/513/2049/feature-flush-cache.
16777216 sectors of 512 bytes
**************************

Press `ESC' to enter the menu... 4   
Press `ESC' to enter the menu... 3   
Press `ESC' to enter the menu... 2   
Press `ESC' to enter the menu... 1   
Press `ESC' to enter the menu... 0   
    [H
    [J  Booting '2.6.32-5-xen-amd64'



root (hd0)

 Filesystem type is ext2fs, using whole disk

kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 root=/dev/xvda1 ro 

initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-xen-amd64



close blk: backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/513/2049
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze1) (dannf@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 02:51:39 UTC 2013
[    0.000000] Command line: root=/dev/xvda1 ro 
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] ACPI in unprivileged domain disabled
[    0.000000] released 0 pages of unused memory
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000]  Xen: 0000000000000000 - 00000000000a0000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  Xen: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  Xen: 0000000000100000 - 00000001e0000000 (usable)
[    0.000000] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x1e0000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x100000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-0000000100000000
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000100000000-00000001e0000000
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: 0170a000 - 02fbb000
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at 0000000000000000-00000001e0000000
[    0.000000] Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-00000001e0000000
[    0.000000]   NODE_DATA [0000000000008000 - 000000000000ffff]
[    0.000000]   bootmap [0000000000010000 -  000000000004bfff] pages 3c
[    0.000000] (8 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 01e0000000]
[    0.000000]   #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
[    0.000000]   #1 [0003ebe000 - 0003ee1000]   XEN PAGETABLES ==> [0003ebe000 - 0003ee1000]
[    0.000000]   #2 [0000006000 - 0000008000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
[    0.000000]   #3 [0001000000 - 00016e9b04]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0001000000 - 00016e9b04]
[    0.000000]   #4 [000170a000 - 0002fbb000]          RAMDISK ==> [000170a000 - 0002fbb000]
[    0.000000]   #5 [0002fbb000 - 0003ebe000]   XEN START INFO ==> [0002fbb000 - 0003ebe000]
[    0.000000]   #6 [0000100000 - 00008df000]          PGTABLE ==> [0000100000 - 00008df000]
[    0.000000]   #7 [0003ee1000 - 00045e5000]          PGTABLE ==> [0003ee1000 - 00045e5000]
[    0.000000] Zone PFN ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      0x00000000 -> 0x00001000
[    0.000000]   DMA32    0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
[    0.000000]   Normal   0x00100000 -> 0x001e0000
[    0.000000] Movable zone start PFN for each node
[    0.000000] early_node_map[2] active PFN ranges
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000000 -> 0x000000a0
[    0.000000]     0: 0x00000100 -> 0x001e0000
[    0.000000] SFI: Simple Firmware Interface v0.7 http://simplefirmware.org
[    0.000000] SMP: Allowing 2 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] No local APIC present
[    0.000000] APIC: disable apic facility
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000
[    0.000000] PCI: Warning: Cannot find a gap in the 32bit address range
[    0.000000] PCI: Unassigned devices with 32bit resource registers may break!
[    0.000000] Allocating PCI resources starting at 1e0100000 (gap: 1e0100000:400000)
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on Xen
[    0.000000] Xen version: 3.4.3-2.6.18 (preserve-AD)
[    0.000000] NR_CPUS:512 nr_cpumask_bits:512 nr_cpu_ids:2 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 30 pages/cpu @ffff88000af4a000 s90392 r8192 d24296 u122880
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s90392 r8192 d24296 u122880 alloc=30*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 
[44691177.425251] Xen: using vcpu_info placement
[44691177.425257] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1937086
[44691177.425259] Policy zone: Normal
[44691177.425262] Kernel command line: root=/dev/xvda1 ro 
[44691177.425278] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[44691177.425643] Initializing CPU#0
[44691177.425931] Checking aperture...
[44691177.432874] No AGP bridge found
[44691177.493621] Memory: 7626464k/7864320k available (3156k kernel code, 384k absent, 237472k reserved, 2068k data, 604k init)
[44691177.493677] SLUB: Genslabs=14, HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[44691177.493707] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[44691177.493716] NR_IRQS:4352 nr_irqs:544
[44691177.493844] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[44691177.493929] console [tty0] enabled
[44691177.494148] console [hvc0] enabled
[44691177.494179] installing Xen timer for CPU 0
[44691177.494219] Detected 2266.746 MHz processor.
[44691177.494229] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4533.49 BogoMIPS (lpj=9066984)
[44691177.494251] Security Framework initialized
[44691177.494259] SELinux:  Disabled at boot.
[44691177.495283] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
[44691177.497852] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
[44691178.155559] Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
[44691178.155717] Initializing cgroup subsys ns
[44691178.155724] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[44691178.155730] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[44691178.155734] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[44691178.155739] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[44691178.155776] CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 32K
[44691178.155781] CPU: L2 cache: 256K
[44691178.155784] CPU: L3 cache: 4096K
[44691178.155789] CPU 0/0x12 -> Node 0
[44691178.155793] CPU: Unsupported number of siblings 16
[44691178.155798] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 26 no PMU driver, software events only.
[44691178.155817] SMP alternatives: switching to UP code
[44691178.180976] installing Xen timer for CPU 1
[44691178.181023] SMP alternatives: switching to SMP code
[44691178.204958] Initializing CPU#1
[44691178.205002] CPU: L1 I cache: 32K, L1 D cache: 32K
[44691178.205003] CPU: L2 cache: 256K
[44691178.205004] CPU: L3 cache: 4096K
[44691178.205008] CPU 1/0x12 -> Node 0
[44691178.205010] CPU: Unsupported number of siblings 16
[44691178.788169] Brought up 2 CPUs
[44691178.788456] devtmpfs: initialized
[44691178.791553] Grant table initialized
[44691178.791564] regulator: core version 0.5
[44691178.791630] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[44691178.792305] PCI: setting up Xen PCI frontend stub
[44691178.792880] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[44691178.792983] ACPI: Interpreter disabled.
[44691178.793009] xen_balloon: Initialising balloon driver with page order 0.
[44691178.793054] vgaarb: loaded
[44691178.793119] PCI: System does not support PCI
[44691178.793125] PCI: System does not support PCI
[44691178.793205] Switching to clocksource xen
[44691178.794506] pnp: PnP ACPI: disabled
[44691178.794791] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[44691178.795127] IP route cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[44691178.796796] TCP established hash table entries: 524288 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
[44691178.799236] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
[44691178.799564] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 524288 bind 65536)
[44691178.799573] TCP reno registered
[44691178.799701] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[44691178.799777] Unpacking initramfs...
[44691178.827376] Freeing initrd memory: 25284k freed
[44691178.895904] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[44691178.895924] DMA: Placing 64MB software IO TLB between ffff88000af8f000 - ffff88000ef8f000
[44691178.895930] DMA: software IO TLB at phys 0xaf8f000 - 0xef8f000
[44691178.896036] platform rtc_cmos: registered platform RTC device (no PNP device found)
[44691178.896293] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[44691178.896313] type=2000 audit(1365849617.234:1): initialized
[44691178.902395] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[44691178.903580] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[44691178.903635] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[44691178.903708] msgmni has been set to 14944
[44691178.903939] alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
[44691178.903992] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[44691178.903999] io scheduler noop registered
[44691178.904002] io scheduler anticipatory registered
[44691178.904006] io scheduler deadline registered
[44691178.904066] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[44691178.909379] registering netback
[44691178.910997] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[44691178.911032] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[44691178.911212] input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input0
[44691178.911254] PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
[44691178.912070] i8042.c: No controller found.
[44691178.912124] mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[44691178.912188] rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[44691178.912233] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[44691178.912238] cpuidle: using governor menu
[44691178.912244] No iBFT detected.
[44691178.912512] TCP cubic registered
[44691178.912609] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[44691178.913241] Mobile IPv6
[44691178.913250] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[44691178.913367] registered taskstats version 1
[44691178.913385] XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/vbd/2049
[44691178.913389] XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/vif/0
[44691178.913392] XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/console/0
[44691178.913409] /build/buildd-linux-2.6_2.6.32-48squeeze1-amd64-qu4MIV/linux-2.6-2.6.32/debian/build/source_amd64_xen/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[44691178.913444] Initalizing network drop monitor service
[44691178.913517] Freeing unused kernel memory: 604k freed
[44691178.913710] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 4344k
Loading, please wait...
[44691178.934413] udev[56]: starting version 164
[44691178.967237] Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver.
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
[44691179.649599] EXT4-fs (xvda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.

INIT: version 2.88 booting

Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd[44691185.554840] udev[153]: starting version 164
.
Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...done.
Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...[44691186.889589] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input1
done.
hostname: the specified hostname is invalid
Activating swap...done.
Checking root file system...fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/xvda1: clean, 74337/524288 files, 922654/2097152 blocks
done.
Loading kernel modules...done.
Cleaning up ifupdown....
Activating lvm and md swap...done.
Checking file systems...fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
done.
Setting up networking....
Mounting local filesystems...done.
Activating swapfile swap...done.
Cleaning up temporary files....
Configuring network interfaces...Setting kernel variables ...done.
dhcpcd.sh: interface eth0 has been configured with new IP=10.49.6.210
done.
Cleaning up temporary files....
startpar: service(s) returned failure: hostname.sh ... 
    [31mfailed!
    [39;49m

INIT: Entering runlevel: 2

Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel 2.
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 2097152 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

Starting enhanced syslogd: rsyslogd.
Starting SASL Authentication Daemon: saslauthd.
Starting web server: apache2Apache/2.2.16 mod_ssl/2.2.16 (Pass Phrase Dialog)
Some of your private key files are encrypted for security reasons.
In order to read them you have to provide the pass phrases.

Server example.com:443 (RSA)
Enter pass phrase:
```

If this is the case, how can I get past that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One thing that may be causig the problem is that a passphrase is required for my ssl certificate on apache, because that is the last thing I can see in the syslog.

Yes, that's your problem, and as EC2 doesn't offer direct console access, there's no way around it. You need to use passphrase-less SSL keys, or prevent Apache from automatically starting when the instance does (so you can manually start it after boot).

If you need to get at stuff on this instance, you'll have to mount its EBS volume onto another instance to recover the data, as this server isn't going to start again like this.

Comment: Agreed. I've detailed the recovery process over here in [this](http://serverfault.com/a/477492/20815) answer.