# My EC2 Ubuntu server was bounced after do-release-upgrade and never came back up. How can I recover?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I had an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 server, running a few websites, and I left it to have an unattended do-release-upgrade. The server said that a reboot was required. I (tried to reboot) it and it never came up. Since trying to reboot, I have not succeeded in getting it to serve a webpage or shell in to it.

What are my options or next steps to recover? Is there a way to download a disk image and recover from that?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried simply stopping it and restarting it since it failed?

Comment: Yes; I've tried rebooting it, and nothing has worked.

Comment: advice for the future, always create an ami of your server before running any kind of update, failures are common and restoring from an ami takes seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't download a disk image (at least not easily).

Here's my recommendation:

1. Fire up a new ubuntu server and configure it as you wish. This will become the replacement for your failed server.
2. Detach the disk from your old server and attach as a second disk to the new server. I cover this basic process in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/477492/20815).
3. Copy over any data you need from the old disk to the new one.
4. Detach the old disk and terminate that old instance.