# Can't access EC2 Instance through SSH After iptable Flush

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, iptables

Before i was able to connect to my EC2 instance, then after i flush the IPTABLE, i can't access it anymore, every time i try to connect, it get TIME OUT.

Error i receive:

```
FAIL: TIMEOUT
[SSH] FAIL: xx.xx.xx.xx:2020 - No connection was made because the operation was stopped.
```

**Problem trying to solve before this problem happen.**
Couldn't access my WHM through IP, but i had access to SSH, i read somewhere you need to flush IPTABLE, then the problem start raising and could't access SSH.

**Steps i have taken (failed)**

1. I have already Restart the Instance.
2. I try to see if IP work in Browser(tried Safari, Firfox, Chrome), same the IP time out in browser.
3. I have checked Security Group and I Allow Traffic from anywhere in Inbound & Outbound.
4. Google Search for 2 Days now, no answer that i can relate to, cause i need
   access to SSH, most of the answer are about Command line.
5. Change IP of Instance (i know this is really un-useful).
6. Try to Understand "Get System Log", but couldn't understand it well,
   cause everything in there seems fine.
7. Try to Access using Public DNS
8. Create a new Security Group with Open VPC connection

**Server info:**
Centos 6
Running WHM & cPanel

A few consideration that I'm currently thinking it could be are (no information are online about these consideration online)

1. VPC Set-up of Security Group
2. Amazon side Bug (i doubt it)

Comment: is it EBS backed?

Comment: @WaleedHamra No i don't have any EBS Snapshot, but the EBS Volumes are still running

Comment: if it's an EBS backed instance, you can mount the volume in another instance, and edit the files... create an iptables fix in the autostart scripts..

Comment: @WaleedHamra Thank you, EEAA has provide me with the info. Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

You've flushed *all* of your iptables rules, including the default ALLOW rules. You'll need to do a full recovery of these systems in order to re-gain access.

If you have not saved the iptables rule changes to disk, there's a chance that rebooting will resolve the issue. If that is not the case, though, you'll need to go through the process I outline in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/477492/20815) to recover the instance.

As an aside, if you're worried about losing the contents of this server, you're doing sysadmin wrong. You should **always** be able to lose a server without significant data loss. This holds true with VPS servers as well as physical servers.

Comment: I have Clients and There Website Files in there, How can i do this without damaging any users?

Comment: I added an edit for you...

Comment: thank you, let me go head and try your guideline, and i really appreciate if you show me where can i find more information on sysadmin

Comment: When i create instance and trying to attach the First(main) volume i get an error "Error attaching volume: 'vol-XXXX6522' with Marketplace codes may not be attached as a secondary device."

Comment: You're using a marketplace image. You'll need to go through the vendor then.

Comment: There is no Vendor Link i see when you wanna create a Instance

Comment: The original server you're trying to fix is a meeker place image. Therein lies the problem.

Comment: I have figure out another way, basically you create an Snapshot and you create Instance from that Snapshot, here is the instruction. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html

Comment: Now that i have create the New instance from snapshot it still give me the same problem. "Time out"

Comment: Talk with your vendor. Period.

Comment: Amazon Charge $100 just for support. WOW lol

Comment: @EEAA maybe that _Period_ wasn't necessary.